# Samsung note 3 forgot password

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

How do I open my phone when I forgot my password it keeps saying you going to have to fully reboot the whole phone after so many tries I forgot the password and need help I don't want to wipe my phone

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there may not be any easy way to get your phone back without losing data. After all, that's the point of password-protecting it.

However, you might be able to mitigate the damage (= retrieve some data before wipe) by doing the following :

1- If you **had activated USB debugging** in the Developers options prior to forgetting your password, you can connect your phone to a computer with a USB cable and access your internal storage using the Android Debug Bridge (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#ADB). More precisely, the `adb pull` command would be helpful.

2- If you **had installed an alternative recovery**, such as Team Win Recovey Projet/TWRP (http://twrp.me/), you can boot to the recovery by holding the "volume up" + "home" + "power" buttons at the same time while the phone is off, the release the power button while still holding the other two.
From the recovery, you can make a backup of your data. Doing so will allow you to try other, more advanced recovery procedures withou fear of losing your data.

Please note that :

- Wiping your data may not delete your internal storage, so those above
  options may not be needed at all.
- Both those options require that you took some actions *before* losing your password.